# How to control a menu with different buttons?

Tags: flutter

I want to be able to open and close a specific menu from around the app, but I have trouble making the menu behave the same.

A menu is closed when tapping outside of its area, which is fine, but it also triggers when pressing another button. But what if I want the other button to control the menu just like its origin?

How do I make multiple buttons open the same menu and behave the same?

Example of issue:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final MenuController _menuController = MenuController();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              MenuAnchor(
                controller: _menuController,
                builder: (context, controller, child) {
                  return FilledButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.isOpen
                          ? controller.close()
                          : controller.open();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Test'),
                  );
                },
                menuChildren: const [
                  Text('Option 1'),
                  Text('Option 2'),
                  Text('Option 3'),
                ],
                child: const Text('Button'),
              ),
              FilledButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _menuController.isOpen
                      ? _menuController.close()
                      : _menuController.open();
                },
                child: const Text('Another Button'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, do you want all buttons to open / close the menu or only one button?

Comment: When 'Another Button' is clicked, the menu closes for a while and then immediately opens again @ClevinoAlrin